# How do i push a variable after using split function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, split, push

> error:  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'push' of undefined    error line: "  this.name[i].push(arrayData[0]);
>   "

I do not understand since the line before    console.log("data is loaded:" + arrayData[0]); is working!

Is it something about async? Can someone please help me out?

Here is my code:

```
 data: {
    name: []
  },
  methods: {
    LoadData: function() {
      console.log("onload fundtion. \n");
      fetch('http://localhost/store/skininfor.txt')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((data) => {
          //  console.log(data);
          var textByLine = data.split("\n");
          for (var i = 0; i < textByLine.length; i++) {
            var arrayData = textByLine[i].split(",");
            console.log("data is loaded:" + arrayData[0]);
            if (arrayData[0] !== undefined) {
               this.name[i].push(arrayData[0]);
            }
          }
        });
    },
```

Comment: this.name[i] does not exist

Comment: should be `this.name.push(arrayData[0]);`

Comment: push method exists on array, as this.name[i] is undefined, so this method is not available on undefined.

Comment: Can you provide the data that you get from the response ?

Answer (score 0):

By this way `this.name[i].push(arrayData[0]);` you are trying to push an element into another element this is why you have that error.

`this.name` is the tab and `this.name[i]` is one element so it should be `this.name.push(arrayData[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

you don't have any element in the name array therefore you should push like this.

```
this.name.push(arrayData[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You *probably* need to assign instead of pushing, i.e.

```
this.name[i] = arrayData[0];
```

(Although I can't be sure. If you defined example input data and desired output, that would be helpful).